# Attach image file as inline attachment in email from amazon S3 using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, inline-attachments

Is there any possibility to fetch an image file from amazon s3 and sent it as inline attachment in an email using rails. I want to fetch the image from s3 based on some criteria while sending email.

Comment: Are you storing images at aws? and which gem are you using for images?

Comment: I am using Paperclip.This is the scenario. when user1 upload some pictures of article they want to sell, it is stored in S3. when a user2 want to buy that article from user1, he will send a message on top of that article. so i want to send a email notification to user1 with the picture of the article he uploaded, so that it will be easy for the user1 to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is possible. Just precise you want an attachment.

For example, in case of user profile pic on S3:

```
require 'open-uri'

attachments.inline["profilepic"+"."+extension] = open(profilepic_url).read
```

It is important that your attachment has an extension which is matching its mime type. And profile pic URL is the absolute path to your image.

**NB**: if your images are protected on S3, the path to your image should be a temporary link instead of a permanent link. Make this link "working" for a few minutes or even more in case your mailing task is asynced. So that the link is still working when the job is processed.